# The difference between INVITED and CONNECTED in WifiP2pDevice

Tags: android, wifip2p

As per the title, what is the differece between **INVITED** and **CONNECTED** in WifiP2pDevice.

I could't find answer everywhere, who can help me ?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Phone A discovers Phone B and attempts to initiate a connection, Phone A will track the Phone B device as `INVITED`. If Phone B accepts the invitation, Phone A will be notified and change the status to `CONNECTED`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I had know the differences between them.